# Which astronaut travelled farthest from Earth?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, apollo-program, record

To-date who has flown farthest from the center of the Earth?
Is he alive now?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Currently, the crew of Apollo 13 holds the record for highest altitude above earth with 400,171 kilometers (248,655 mi) on 7:21 pm EST, April 14, 1970 (source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_13#Spacecraft_location)). That would be 406,542 km when measured from the center of the earth.

The crew members were:

- [Jim Lovell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Lovell) (still alive)
- [Jack Swigert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Swigert) (died 1983)
- [Fred Haise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Haise) (still alive)

It should, however, be noted that this record wasn't intentional. The original mission plan was to enter a low Moon orbit, send the lander to the surface and back, and then return to earth. But due to a technical malfunction of the service module during the flight from earth to moon, the moon landing was canceled and the mission returned back to earth on a [free return trajectory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_return_trajectory) which lead it further away from earth than any of the other Apollo flights.

Comment: Also they hold the record for fastest humans ever, right?  Re-entry speed on a free return was higher than a standard Apollo re-entry.  (Which is funny since Top Gear US on the first show, had Buzz Aldrin as the fastest human they could get).

Comment: @geoffc Speed depends on your reference frame. When you use the center of the galaxy as your reference frame, you are currently traveling with 250 km per second.

Comment: I'm guessing he means relative to earth :)

Comment: @ContextSwitch Which point on earth? :)

Comment: The center of the earth

Comment: @Philipp In which direction?  I.e. Did Apollo 13's reentry occur in the direction of the galactic centers motion?  :)

Comment: At the moment when they were at their greatest distance from Earth, which of the three of them was in the chair on the far side of the capsule?

Comment: @KeithThompson - at the point when they were orbiting the moon they were sheltering in the Aquarius Lunar Module (which had more reliable life support than the severely damaged CSM).  The Lunar Module does not have seats, its likely they were moving around to look out of the two windows and so its impossible to say who was further away.  Nice idea though, it would have been one of them at some point.