# Astronaut distance from Earth?

Tags: nasa, astronauts, record

After the Apollo Missions, what is the farthest that any country has sent astronauts into space (distance from Earth)?

Comment: Welcome to *Space!*  Do you only want missions that happened after the last Apollo lunar mission in December 1972?  After the Apollo-Soyuz Test Project in 1975?  Or any mission not including Apollo?  Please clarify the question, as it does matter.

Comment: *Different* but related question: [Puzzler: Precisely what maximum distance from the Earth did the Apollo 13 astronauts achieve?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33211/12102)

Comment: @peterh: Which Apollo?  The lunar landing missions only, or Skylab and ASTP as well?

Comment: I just want to clarify. Yes, I know the Apollo missions sent astronauts the furthest into space than any other missions ever. My question is: what is the farthest astronauts have been out in space, excluding the Apollo missions.

Answer (score 13):

Highest altitude of all manned missions excluding Apollo: [Gemini 11](http://astronautix.com/a/astronautstatistics.html), 1372 km

(leaving this here for reference: )
Highest altitude dated after Apollo: Space Shuttle [STS-31R](http://www.vibrationdata.com/space/Shuttle.html) (the Hubble launch), 620 km.

Comment: That's kinda sad, IMHO.

Comment: It's sad we haven't gone beyond Earth orbit. High Earth orbits on the other hand, add risk for little to no reward, which is why all recent manned missions have been in pretty low orbits.

Comment: @EricDuminil It's way better than the farthest we've sent humans the opposite direction (into the crust/mantle)

Comment: The reason is largely the Van Allen belts.  Radiation is much worse outside them, and especially bad while going through them.  Not good for either crew or equipment.

Comment: @Punintended: Ahah. At first I thought, "wait, it's also low Earth orbit in the opposite direction!".