# What is the velocity of the ISS relative to the Earth's surface?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, iss, mathematics, earth, velocity

This was asked once before, but I believe there was no clear answer given and accepted.

The ISS has an orbital period of 92.9 minutes, or 5574 seconds. If it were in a completely equatorial orbit, this would give it a surface speed of 7190 m/s (40,075,000 / 5574). However, the ISS also has an orbital inclination of 51.64 degrees, meaning as it moves the surface of the earth also moves at a speed of roughly 464 m/s.

I've tackled this problem several times but my high school trigonometry fails me. How would one go about calculating this?

EDIT: Since asking this question I've realized the surface speed depends on the ISS's latitude, and varies quite a bit over an orbit. A more clear question to ask would be - how would one derive a function for surface velocity dependent on latitude?

Comment: The inclination of the ISS' orbit means that its speed relative to the Earth's surface beneath it varies constantly over its orbit, even if that orbit was circular. Do you want a maximum, a minimum, an average, or a range?

Comment: @notovny Yes, I failed to account for this when I was doing my own calculations. My original intent was to figure out how far you'd travel across the earth's surface in a period of time, but I've since realized that it's fairly complex. Wouldn't there be a function dependent on the latitude that could be calculated, and then using that be able to calculate speed at specific points, as well as deriving the maximum, minimum, average, and range based on that function?

Comment: It will involve more than just latitude as the direction of travel of the ISS changes relative to the Earth's surface.  If you really want to do it, there are a multitude of implementations of the SDP4/SGP4 algorithm which will compute the IIS's position and velocity (just search for SGP4 and your language of choice).  You'll want the results in the ECEF frame, and that directly gives you the velocity relative to the Earth's surface.  This is a descent place to start: http://celestrak.org/software/vallado-sw.php

Comment: @GregMiller Thank you! I'll have a read.

Comment: Do you mean "ground speed"?  I don't think many people call it "surface velocity".

Comment: @Wyck I've heard "surface velocity" used in space-travel contexts previously. But, yes I mean the same thing as "ground speed". Basically how fast the ISS's theoretical "shadow" travels across the Earth's surface.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

JPL [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/) has trajectory data for the [International Space Station](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=-125544), SPKID = -125544

> Revised: Nov 23, 2022
> Trajectory is TLE-based. Predicts run for 4 weeks into future, but are of low accuracy for times more than a few days past the revision date above.

Horizons can give position and velocity vectors of the ISS relative to the centre of the Earth in the ICRF frame. Unfortunately, it doesn't do the ECEF frame, so I improvised an approximate solution using the geometry of the [WGS84 ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System). The Earth's polar axis points in the Z direction of the ICRF frame.

First we find where the position vector intersects the ellipsoid surface. We need the distance from that intersection point to the Earth's axis to determine the rotation speed at that latitude. The rotation velocity vector at that point is perpendicular to the position vector and to the Earth's axis. Once we have that velocity vector we can subtract it from the velocity vector of the ISS. Hopefully, I haven't made any blunders with my geometry or algebra. ;)

The top graph below shows a typical result, over ~2 orbits, with a 1 minute time step. It gives a mean speed of ~7376 m/s. The second graph shows the raw ISS speed relative to the centre of the Earth. The third graph shows the Earth rotation speed. That is, the speed in the top graph is derived from the vector difference of the 2nd graph minus the 3rd graph.

[image: ISS ground speed graph]

[image: ISS raw body speed]

[image: Earth rotation speed]

Here's the ISS geocentric declination over the same timespan.

[image: ISS Declination]

Note that times in the speed plots are in [TDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_Dynamical_Time), the declination plot uses UTC.

Here's my Sage / Python [speed plotting script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyVWP9z2sYS_z0z-R-uSl-RHCwjOXZs3jCvJMGt22A8QNtpCdHI6AQX61t1hw3x-H9_u3uSkLDTec8zBrS397ndvf0qwzDYmKtc8DvOslQKJdKE_cDueJQuhNrCj4VKcxb4ymdhnsbs5zQXX9NEshDIPlN-vuSK3aTB9uULBn85j3wlAE2lTK04W_J0wROV8zY-JmzhR4s1sHC9mqfrJGAq9xe3TGacBywNaeXbiH_8NDl7w3gUiUymImgzHxCyKFVMKPvlC73pj1woBcfdbNn1kLljkSyZ23Edu3NuO-eaZ5gGIhRwJKqS5jdCFSIAo0uMZ88wPiMy8TuO7b55-cIwDJRBxFmaK4Zq5_zvNZdKvnxBBgzXCZg0jSQreKJ87S38xYoXDLGvUJtI3NhKLG55XjJOwHZ-fpHmwKF4jseE5QPr7S-ba8lHYSi56l34keQW8q_zCDiNlVKZ7B4dSRnYX7LITnzp28v07sjPxNGquGEvFBG3gQIKwad3x3OJ3gH7wYyk5Ss29L-gH2yELC_uyfWIhN2KKI3BzTgY4X4pPR9ATo_fntnO8VtEuYhQ5AQuCVSCNYcdMff8zHZP3rque3J6TEeJpDhKg9wAowY7YKbDDlloFehumxZu3JLjc0n57GqxL9-PL5gUAc-5H4F3b1FKyRdpEgA6_JBexnMPF3rs7NQ5fQP-cHbeOT49d8AayRJcOPf07fdYYrogQyZA6vpWsviNL7m3iJGNXGPY_3XgDa5_HgyB0vpzMGm9fEGP3vTP6wHSfh-8n47GSB_9NvV-u7qcTpD86_AQaePBhXf9sX9FrBfj_nBQECd_TqYaFJUDIuB470fjMZKuRleDgvSx_27wcaKJBenD4OO0700r2vvJ797FaDzsT3cyjt794n3oT_uNjdP-u48kiNuqPP_Hyp_N2N9I8ZX3RKLMYwvMEfCQhVwtVh4mFFMnjzaT8IO-0gw_eWZ1deBpu4WE_N33309GFy9fPJQWfQRBR8Nh_-oDSvCgwR5R_MHVdEBq_3h8fg6EybQ_nnrTyyHJ-kDHPRJ9dF0np5mmDq69yeVfJZUTFY4f4PEkC8r2KstRLxDEKvPU37CjjHYbsqkyId7alDx7Dy0dq60uaym-Ua3HNsMAk7AikmyNC2YL0FptVNt6LFB3UZdzW3I_X6zM3OhfX7LfB-PJ5eiq-0kemJ8mB5ZBqcZGcMvGLJWZTgEiwgrnux6rBXNhZ_zT6oTGH36OgdhleEa5C8L7ofgNct-sFYQ60OQiF5nCVcyMDzXgR8MqU3G8J7v5H2l9-v4T3ObAtA_o52A0qEtfCR0j9FWa8CdyGlcjRmEzGF9ODGt_eQ9KX49a5wmhNS5wjzUSCZf6HolsyywSiqhmwVJI8Ckx7C-pSExanJ10ndO5VWlNFbPH4uomZk53rpeKmrlvldj6PN1VU5b4Mae7tQ8-Wf90uVheqQA8gXuvV_4_uMJOKH-blRGqz0DdMIRllGbczDptljllqBpTyP20UBYCNIvuGbIO1u7MKSJnAxu3HRA46xQEBwgOEpyGDOYW0_q2Y0FiNTf4e9OxSiFu-FdTeRBlpQSvWD_L8nQjYuouIEmD0LKNKdmHH8xXjFN6pztY4gXMtCYHmUUOnGEV-CoyjQva49fM7c6t-XO79HLXhWX2mtZe760dFntLAd-tRRSwd_yrgGtZrPM7XoqT3QEwHn1AH1qxNoIW16LIaG12h4ZL4N5M2FN6ACGhZIWcPpQ1eCzMm6f3uGZqiFIXVBhudguQqDag1YIsQD0VGFx1asQNEGHliB3XiChUgGUSJDsAHsTD7x3LKzbY-AtV6o3C7RZJ1Nc9uOsOmG8L_yZAwsnBFq_dtRAMz3RroZze22ABuE0TtYI9eCwBwF4wm4miE00DIQUerHktH2ijQX-TIQ5AWo0DatZ8Yv7CbA1f1XDtQjsogwIjBtTW3hr7kCh0NPWMQ8c9OXnzxmgjAlWjnoE95OFVenfosE630zF0OWzQj7uOpnOgn8R6e5wGvDfhEfXp5qxVdstQRloY-PitW9bWHGNBM3pqm_FeK_cDkbYsAoKA5wR9Cm4nYihM03wN7WuQqvIn6Vj-TqM07xnLnPOkUARL_Rk0WiJQqx6EtLxb6tYTrLJWqbfO8IyiG-1WST6Bzt3EU6AH10dYT9O91hBjOOK-VAyyOOaZxjbjSbYvIw8az3WELv2k-bAlDD-ZqU2Af3QdFZUuof7Eq6ddlSrQv12qUsazFY95Dix6ksL7-O7b8taTr4eZu8zA9ECpHo9sVBr8eqZYFaszqdfMVrtlzbqHzpwSgMTQR5bC1V8hEb2_IHfLegrh8e89IV-xa1zTFoOZEU3FfllHwse9Wwkk8qlG0byAetAFJz5A9FlnTumzwTFNu1BNSg4QtGAp0iAmxlps0gm1Z5RftEsVeLIGqwOLiWB1t8KchCOcwoEUEoBPMy6vpQc_QgLaGrJNluoC-RzATuX2cyP0bssXGIYOgAN6JJzCZmGU-tAi6tqzRnnhqFrOoRqkefUYbhabZ93judXeJx535w0JsX-C5IAdn84ENfW1Bh84uFSMZXoAV7iC45VP0lfj__0KJiSs5vtbK0WLFwSU7aDSQjg-MwTWxSpdJ_2CAY23WUCkSTHgy3Ue-ou9IzPqD1JpJ9hGR5BrAtNqssjEpR5i5s4_u82lhXRprDxEpifARz0m_86ViQBH5ej4mjbpR9-19hUAEzkY8jDrYQER-FIjxzbnLz0N_wDA6A9gGHz3AB2IWIBRb--F3NOMkKornh2CAs4cWysIjzbrzLECNibO5vbymnu9KtHvXXRxCJ0ROc01Drn4n9jBYnpTrRRiCJZ100SnBg66FhNFdTqdjrUXKkP_luuiovw4kw0fFexfVe1BJTp74mxjOGEVY5AXMVlkMuyoj-d7zG0WQ8kCXthW8BmHxt7tKQQL4IZjbDmwwXtiUhL2GcPAVmhWsPeHrSBVeYYNGQt6_M4eEinWsJWStRmBR5Rly-d6DwES7jrcXcodckg1NS9QUYoNCXWbkE3L82E6q8iYQkt6jNt7-gDoqZHtEDEaKTg0hprtAdm79nH4yOIjadTEmFDO12_w_GwFNR_SBz7GlXzU_2v-a8DCJ-zWorRNTNSTrUTxMC8bCvps6ylMbSPeM7rl7V2j5XFiMUk-AwFqaI39xTss5Uce5IplEkP17Bm5WK7UU7jQ2ClqNMT6n1AjHqqdberhWPViNUdSUJ85vdT4Sb9IrN56PtTq_SM4mN7Dozrifh7foU2ehXny8lS_iy1HNEr7taMauWCHPS7rQiWrrhc3UCbun5FbY9zeA50iTSyUWeISao8-2zAdwh7dUJbry1wEdPu92WwNfrsrjhRL4ChGjO8cjTm2qYtbr3oF2nMPZtXDvAL0N1x6kQ-yAqSxK9YGIh1JhkA1Ho_aWMd2TvD9zJKe8KP0GtvjWPe92_tA2rqjNbWmdRfAvrRmSvI1qgWynC0J-KThYLuOkhLB_v4bGp-8zFcrs8wUzd3VHBwE9dZrCyUeJpbYx_nt2sZHbGbxl7-pWt8tJU3ggQmMvg9pI6b0jt052bVXmMUgu1ZXsi8nxRRlbUp4OH2FEDSksCGhdkdGu54li0niJvIXtwYWkxzutRliuvk1Gip-WcMY4INHQheRo3sW7xJI2Q0o0N5XfFMpvtGKP2OMYn7WsDCVbrQlNmSJo6ZlSo-Q4Px6h0eCmB37DGu2BjnSA1Ele1i08Eb5nt2GOcnAW4dvisHaUpYsjeoY_46btHvnKLClZn7KwinUGs0GDg42AzlYuFfJMCGvVByZoQ2VIKiGGblK781r6787gGpg&lang=sage).

It can also be used on other Earth satellites. Horizons has several other satellites in its database, eg the Hubble has id# -48. Type `mb` into the `target` field for the full list of major bodies (spacecraft are towards the end). You can also type body names into the `target` field. Horizons will respond with a list of matching bodies if the name is ambiguous.

Here's the [declination script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyVGP1z2kb2d8_4f9jIubPkYBlI3Wu40bQklhPSYCjQdlLMaRa0AsWSVtWubIjH_3vf29UXONe5Y8aIfd_v7fuSDcMgEyazkN0z4rNVFCZUhjwhPpWUBBmPyQeehV95IkjAM0KJpNmaSbLk_u74iMAnYxGwALvkhCaELwXL7sNkTVYskQxYEp-kEZcklDY5PtJMv2ehlCwhyx0ZD0l3gvTddrdjt9_YnTeaZsj9MAiZrxQDsmt3Onb38vjIAKNRUBinPJNgQAv-_syZkOL4SNkc5MlKch4JUtBEWe6t6GrDCoKYSrQpCpe2DFd3YGZBOF3RiGbXPAMKtB71BNXJOcSbuWCjIBBMOtc0EsxSDHkWAamxkTIVvYsLIXz7SxrZCRXUXvP7C5qGF5sirF4QRswGiHF8BN_ePcsEXgDwQzS0o-jwLzlNZChDBj6-IOrTsUlfSHAHL3BFJn3yT3LlvivwZ6QL-DSlGdzDc-R3DWT_D0C6nyrB_7LJJw6OElpSiNBnGQOIDGNW0r3-7hnddPSpP2kQgZ7uM6INzzEt1hGr73JJBfNWsY9-GxCKYf9n13PHH9yh89mdHh-pn97s89h1Rm-n7uQ3d3J89Muv_ZvZYDZwp04H9E3ca2_6eToDnsG7yfXx0bv-J-96NBn2Z87b0ezD8dFsMHS9q8H7wWzqDAc3v85QdP_mfUl15b6H83jcn7g3M6c_mHxyp0DxbvpbSaGMGb396F31Z33nZlR78FOVY2ZMtyL8ypwwkeZryzo-8llAAiZXGw_rytQ11CoqpEUEACQ-eIrfDL4hDZZcMGeW5czq6YLQ4QlUfF68fDkdgYuPZeCewMzRcNi_uXJOH7WCp1OAgSPuBEBaF4Kms_5k5mEoAKxUa-hoXAN5qmHu2JsO_tAwpmCg2EXFygq06iTN0E8wwSobwp9gZlmRdsqFNKEiWqqnOI-nupxOe-RUsq08fWoRLAEBmDBJc0SYpyDttIUOW0-F1LouMmYLRrPVxsyM_nhAIBWmg9FN71acmbfTM8tQ7cBG4Za9zniemp1CSBhUcl44pFFuRYTxo90JjN9plkBb6hHUUXKFgjwWv8HuZS6J3ABMrLIwlYjFXvXYEPxkWFXTiw-MN38U1u3LW7hI17TP1E935DbNr6yOUfYNT9gzQ42bEVHF4U4GU8M6RB-I0vcj8yxR0irTdGAw454pOJDAoj0aGBhM6OtWVLZIo1AqqPnMGOM2MewvPExMRTC_7HW-X1h1gNTQcUhc3dq801toVDF2DgMYW_-Z1QOJJDRmKg_ss1vr7xKhmE3fEPdOY_4_cUVI0f4W2a9u5RzWv4h4ysy03SJpp6xoY7ZhGkF4AKnEVDz13E3bOFHTTlFmW2DctcHitF0AOgDoIKCzZ4QJwHMgtcgFMbf4e9u2KiuW7KspPajJ0oQTHAMZ34ZQkzDDoS2D2QLaEFvBwBGESsISXxS3sMYrmGtXzlJLpXtKwoR8DVMtF_zHx7zbW1iLb3FpdK8LaPJK4V4d4M4Vb5UVJ-RtHkY-ecu-hhDPVZ7ds9Ke9B4ko-4z9aU9a6HU4makChv0UwxdAldnAk-ZBEoSmlYYCuMJ868IcMYfEGdqEaUz6DFc7g5Eot8grVENPjoqIeSy3QBuAQiYC_K6AUSjIMUctOwMaFAePmuSE-Ju6UqWfqNxNVKZ-sqB225D_HbwZ4JI0Ozv8OK7FgpDnd1G4fMHGyIA12miV8CDapUA4IWwmWi6gmlBCIGDtWhUsg4aLCwpygGR1p6CRjSfhb8I2162anEt7Y8aoyFWDfit8zWm0C10RTlGp22UZeUYP71-88ZooTA1wxwD98fzjzQ5b3cMPUwVrKtgGsQAdOlrLihWpiDft9TCIvQGB7fCpVBzt6WtK3_ziIPak6DdLtTiiP-hRR5CX24cqEZxvy5llOO7ONJcci9PUWWxJ_aarTeB7dhEtYQX-W097_NTFjHIBqjHiFEhCbZvaBp7bMbzNl-qyZjII0zPZ3uIDTskFI9VhrY6l7JUfGsqjGzzxBqn0u_iWQ-wQv1_n2KcsHTDYpYBiX754Hniv_gbj5rd1sNWXTqgDqq3o8690YKPb4yoAjsXGmeetk6tee-8s1DlLrDQkaRI7BMEYq4X4F45KaEY_n1o5QkZI1IHEdZsjB75mEchReadAJDKRE1dROMaBkAPMvYMxc_bC9Uu9yhmvAfjo6QASxVJpVU1wkYtKhWNM3oQtkonWJJD4IHERGnN3MMeJLEaCWzwUPA0U6Ia7YBGCMBo8wewtLJgn7t2GP2t3zNr2i9-SyHQyCDiVIVzni_0jMnRTBNq7NJqdJdi9QRHSu5GtqgQlH3KrAisAwuH9I7p-pc0TkWNgqQNyT-qNkEcGAyNyOBnF4PUTYyBLeJQ5I91QNciMagHMuAoSIxz44BKohwfmnGMHR0H6D4eDFJ2HhhRsMIswPUKWMGgUocNGQJbVPtAkvJpLzRSNNcwFumKKAF7Tdpp7BCNLB8yvN_Dm5URx8avxjqkcWkILM0VGHO3hMcoxNF6YHtBsnOUsZf7gTHUZI9I3rNfB0-geJ0xJoymRVNVcbhUrTOabqBPy406Ki1Y_5pyDKLwhEMx4i2FVqNvExaHRdn91XdLL71yFzHH6IFKQkpBcAm4HprKQgNlNATuiShe_yWNPBqF6ySGzuUYWbjeyDIvanGBUbtq7Fn2P0mNWKCEarF3D9AxVaqFK2mWiSGhIzInMK4a_wOC6fLYaK9PhMKbDmOJ3k8fG832CTKvGhdBBhA9NEvQOgt9FTRnPs-xS1Q1rVIR4mvEYcIzY4GzeHXnVf9ycbpn8-qwqATSLRNeRJfwNuLMjbq7QHT2XDCLxLAIim5weWp6d-zOJb5-rtUJv8rY2x7D1uXdPfjC1pPb1JGzmpMbp2-jHtWVpfCCI0W5DSvJl3v3VE9FVViH_Eu173kplRuzrLwmdyPF-77fnB47CCLsWDHFjXNs4xGHMv6i22qg71QfAhrYGdXzXDHixti225f1gMDGAA2ruqZDQ1Vuqh6oegjuiwEkn_LYEDGNojopVBvRG9Qyoqs7Q-0KcNf7qapzytj38UsO6w4VKa4_Gd5r8QKkvN2CB61Dz7eV51vt-TeiUaz8Wiws0lsdiq0KxcV-aMqkEFAKmsNThpht-wcIWyHkQq-CtfFBsYgY5T_7bFgRDbx4eKo36QYqTdZGpYfeM1Nx17kCLI0LUM0M3pkSTQZpj1GDAg0OxgN2t42MIzOwoav6plVIFBv-YI6tvwDlkUNM&lang=sage). Any major body can be the observing `center`, and any body can be the `target`. Please see the [Horizons docs](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/manual.html) for details on specifying bodies and times.

---

Here's a little interactive 3D [ellipsoid script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1VVlvo0gQfrfk_1DC0oQm2AZ7srJGQlppjudIeRgpljNqoLF7g-l20zjHr9-qBgzebHjgqK7jq68OZvCzLKWulcxhX6pUQP0sbHaYTpoQziFYSODMjX_ThOfQ3rDpRGsUaW74UVgjsz-6VHadTye52ONB5WsJS4g3EYPpZDr5W1ZWGJ5ZUijgyGXl8yQOIU2-Lu9CKLlNvtJTVck6CoGXNlkvV_jSWPWn0Tm3IvnFy1qwb9MJ4IUWLg4-A4zJOqmqWqmqRtICZT6HOaQMQXGHiOQzqGUFXyBTNagC7EGMMqII0ja5aHUJNmqjaiosp7A9ErpeQ3ijIDEGKRgEpOp0QnLu3gbl36hZn4z1X59WcAtvT6vRoRG2MRW8ItDf5BQfF7yEQZQluXNUjRF4njeqIWZjxFmVjZWqWgxaPXOyhr1QubCjPEMIKmWDzynowgwfM_iuqrMw1vm0amQ6KNUpcpBSytfsfUiZI22oGLSMYXbhIHJ0OpH7SqG1bu9Nro7YpXinEmDDzrWk3qE7WvjYv9hSq0DLLugD6t33UN9F_tCYgmdi_cMndqnjyWxwy9ilBLXY12gdr7qK2MPQ7XTWRdCkdDdqtB-Gv7ST1Uru8fxhQUPjK80zad-SaLFm_eEtzpYbKKTqmOYcG-ztG2Xhz3nI2fDMVKlM4s02m40XwuCqbyn-KgnK1o_CKHxnUCgD74Bd789TlKRsNwpZykpgSLIZPK_-2ngM21QrnOHLaY28Jbq-Aqx7-iIE1rLXO4k2hTfWrZujP-i3lb22cGH7HiHUNNqIuza82gsfiacCB1hmfGWf-NYH2RbTVXHsDU9G3lzD3HY-l73P_5aPtxwAT9VZuG0xKqiOaEWKzCrjX80oW1TKHHlJjebTasDdNmato1VHF1KDeHE3oq6IPAYfq7SlQmzjHUKOdh_Ve-T3Rv2DqEBaUBWOKMGu237vgMe0yKMrlF2vVys6irer3VPX71lNItpydNheFzfLbq3h0TJ1qw3Vl_yy3q7zjT_Jt4iGfGfaoDbqsj6hx4HlbeTmOt6xPtcT7TUtjBZVLrOm5IaW0iNueGLXRZbVHjg-slJlzy-y7kg4jdzOMWNHa7wlYqPev0Gdk6OpJ6iDZ1jvBBkw7v1_ykUJI0m3cAoWd0PBjMivJmNQR5IfA2LGWT1eWaVlI4bx6MwX9UG9-AXttfZfGVK18eMm5-b5Bh21vYC_hMRTxh7U3nAchMxj_wJJYSMG&lang=sage) I used to verify my maths.

Comment: Very nice! My (obviously flawed) intuition led me to expect more of a sine wave. What accounts for the knee in the curve?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Glad you like it. :) I'm not totally clear on why it has that exact shape, I haven't had time to think about it yet. But I assume it's mostly due to the high inclination of the ISS orbit (~50°).

Comment: I naively expected it to show max ground speed at the highest and lowest latitudes where the rotational speed is least, and minimum when it crossed the equator.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Me too. I don't think the eccentricity of its orbit, or of the WGS ellipsoid have much effect, since they're both quite small. My velocity vector calculation *seems* to behave properly: it doesn't reverse direction in the southern hemisphere. :) But there's still the possibility of error(s) in my code.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It's counter-intuitive because we're subtracting velocity vectors. The Earth velocity vector has no Z component, but the ISS velocity vector's Z component is maximum over the equator and zero when it reaches the north & south extremes of its declination.

Comment: @PM2Ring Fascinating! Doesn't seem to vary as much as I expected it to considering the steep inclination. Still lands roughly in the ballpark where previous answers were. The knee-bend in the middle of each cycle is really fascinating, I was expecting something more akin to a sine wave as Organic Marble said earlier. Thank you!

Comment: @Ludvig The variation is small because the ISS orbit speed is much greater than the Earth rotation speed. I guess I should make a few more graphs to illustrate that. ;)

Comment: @Ludvig I've added a couple more graphs.

Comment: I just noticed there's a minor typo in my speed plotting script. The ellipsoid flattening should be 1/298.257223563 not 1/298.257222563, but the effect of that error is negligible.

Answer (score 7):

The orbital velocity of the ISS is approximately 7.6 km/s, and the Earth's rotational velocity as a function of latitude is $465 \cos i$, where $i$ is the latitude.

Since the ISS is inclined 51.6° to the equator, its velocity vector relative to the ground below (ignoring rotation) is $\langle4720.723,5956.07\rangle \text{ m s}^{-1}$. The maximum latitudes that the ISS can reach are $\pm 51.6^\circ$, so the function relating position to surface velocity would be $v_s =\langle4720.723 - 465\cos i,5956.07\rangle \text{ m s}^{-1}$, whose magnitude will vary between the interval $\boxed{[7320.24,7424.04] \text{ m s}^{-1}}$.

Please let me know if you have any questions, as this may contain errors or be entirely incorrect.

Comment: Interesting! I was expecting the relative speed to actually be higher, but on second thought since both the surface and the station are moving in the same direction it's understandable why the speed would actually be lower. It checks out according to my math, thank you! Since it's a fairly narrow interval, I assume for *general* application ~7324 m/s could be used (the average between the two values), right?

Comment: It is incorrect. The projection of the velocity vector on the surface points in different directions at different points of the orbit. For example, at the northmost and the southermost points of the orbit, it points purely eastward.

Comment: "Velocity is $465 \cos i$, where $i$ is the latitude." Hmmm. Shouldn't there be a unit somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Since none of the other answers actually showed how to compute the ground speed, the below Python script uses [Skyfield](https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield) to compute the ISS's velocity relative to the position on Earth it is directly above.  You can likely find a library to do this is almost any programming language.

```
from skyfield.api import load, wgs84
import math

satellites = load.tle_file('http://celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/stations.txt')
print('Loaded', len(satellites), 'satellites')

iis = {sat.name: sat for sat in satellites}['ISS (ZARYA)']

t=load.timescale().now()
geocentric = iis.at(t)
lat, lon = wgs84.latlon_of(geocentric)
iisll=wgs84.latlon(lat.degrees,lon.degrees)

difference = iis - iisll
topocentric = difference.at(t)
v=topocentric.velocity.km_per_s
vkms=math.sqrt(v[0]*v[0]+v[1]*v[1]+v[2]*v[2])
vms=vkms*0.621371
print(str(vms) + " miles per second")
```

Comment: My answer describes how to compute the ground speed, and the details are in the speed plotting script's source code on lines 145-155, although I admit my code is a little cryptic.

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading something by Randall Munroe / XKCD about this.  By wonderful coincidence, in the time it takes to listen to the song "500 Miles" by The Proclaimers, the ISS travels approximately 500 miles relative to the Earth's surface...or it might actually travel 500 miles plus 500 more, I'm afraid I've forgotten the detail, and as I'm posting this from work I can't access the XKCD website to check  :-)

Comment: https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/ if an astronaut on the ISS listens to I'm Gonna Be, in the time between the first beat of the song and the final lines ... ... they will have traveled just about exactly 1,000 miles.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).