# Why was the Moon's antipode at 10 degrees south on July 1969?

Tags: launch-window, trans-lunar-injection

From what I understand, the TLI burn should be around the Moon's antipode projection on Earth. I get that. What I don't understand is why, according to this picture

https://history.nasa.gov/afj/launchwindow/figs/Fig%209.png

the antipode was at 10 degrees south for the 16th of July 1969? How was this calculated?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think there is an issue with an antipode 10 degrees off the equator? The Moon has an orbital inclination of about 5 degrees to the ecliptic plane,  Depending on where it is in it's nodal precession cycle, the antipode could be as much as 28 degrees off the equator.

Comment: I'm confused. According to https://history.nasa.gov/afj/launchwindow/lw1.html "the injection (TLI) must occur very close to the extension of the earth-moon line at the time of the spacecrafts lunar arrival". But lunar orbit insertion for Apollo 11 occured Jul-19 17:21 UTC (see [here](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=-399110)) and the lunar declination was 10°N ~Jul-18 8:00, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsVVj.png which I created using Horizons data.

Comment: Sorry, make that Jul-18 9:00 https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XG6T.png You can make declination plots using the link near the end of my answer https://space.stackexchange.com/a/61065/38535 The ID for the Moon is 301

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you for the analysis! That's exactly the information I was trying to find. But I guess you looked the wrong time for TLI. The TLI occured on Jul-16 16:22 UTC (on the same link you posted). Unfortunately when I tried using the Horizons app, I could not make a Moon inclination plot like the one you did..

Comment: And what is more confusing, is that according to this site ( https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/Apollo_18-24_Translunar_Injection.htm ), the TLI burn started at 9.9204 N latitude

Comment: Yes, the TLI was at Jul-16 16:22 UTC, but the important antipode is _at the time of the spacecraft's lunar **arrival**_, so somewhere around the time it inserts into the lunar orbit. The Moon's antipode latitude is just the opposite of the Moon's declination. So a 10°S antipode corresponds to a 10°N declination.

Comment: FWIW, my scripts pull data directly from the Horizons API. I have a script specifically for lunar declination at the end of https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/50974/16685 but I  figured that the general declination script was more useful (eg, you could use it to plot the declination of the Apollo 11 S-IVB). If you have any difficulties running any of my Horizons scripts, please let me know.