Topocentric ecliptic coordinates for Moon's nodes from JPL's Horizons
I have been trying to get the ecliptic coordinates for the ascending and descending nodes of the Moon from any observation point on earth. I have used JPL Horizon's ephemeris for osculating elements
Though it gives the longitude of mean ascending node of lunar orbit (OMEGA) but it is only generated with respect to a major body center which is either Earth's geocenter (station code:500) or 2300+ predefined sites, usually radar/radio sites.
I tried specifying the coordinate centre with a lat-long but get the error: Osculating element tables must be body-centered.
I am hoping there is a way within Horizons to get the node's ecliptic  coordinates for any observation centre on Earth and not resort to spherical trigonometry to convert from the values obtained for major body centres. Can someone guide me to directly get this output from Horizons?
Just FYI, I am able to get the ecliptic lat-long for all planets and the Moon from any observation site on earth using the Observer Table ephemeris, with a few custom table settings.

You can't use those predefined sites for osculating elements tables, you get the must be body-centered error message. I just checked using Greenwich (site 0@399) in the Web app and in the API via my Python script here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/55112/16685

Why do you need the Moon's nodes in topocentric coords? I don't think you can get that directly from Horizons, you have to do some 3D geometry. And if you're that fussy, you should use the WGS84 ellipsoid, not spherical trig. I have a simple example of WGS84 geometry here: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/61065/38535 which may be helpful, if you can read Python.
